# Laravel: Form Submission - Custom URL Structure for Route Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have this form in my laravel project:

```
<form class="d-flex" method="GET" action="{{ route('client.info.get', ['input' => '']) }}" id="infoForm">
    <div class="btn-group ipchi-searchbox" role="group" aria-label="">
        <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control form-control-lg custom-rounded-input" placeholder="جستجوی آی پی یا دامین" aria-label="Enter IP address" aria-describedby="search-btn" value="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" id="search-btn-ip">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the route that handles the action of this form:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'client.'], function(){
    Route::group(['as' => 'info.', 'prefix' => 'info'], function(){
        Route::get('/{input?}', [IpInfoController::class, 'getInfo'])->name('get');
    });
});
```

And this is the Controller method that handles the request:

```
public function getInfo(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'input' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid input.'], 400);
        }

        $inputValue = $request->input('input');

        if (filter_var($inputValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
            $data = $this->getIpInfo($inputValue);
        } else {
            $data = $this->getDomainInfo($inputValue);
        }

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Now it works fine and when I submit the form, I get this in the url:

`https://example.com/info?input=google.com`

But I need to display it in the url like this:

`https://example.com/info/google.com`

So how to do this?

Comment: Redirect to the URL after the form has been submitted?

Comment: Laravel is not _creating_ that format, the browser is - because that is how a standard form submission works. So you can either redirect the "wrong" format, after the request was received on the server side - or intercept the form submission on the client side using JavaScript, _build_ the URL format you want to use, and then navigate there using `location.href = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add javascript code to your blade file

```
 document.getElementById('search-btn-ip').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var inputValue = document.querySelector('input[name="input"]').value;
        var form = document.getElementById('infoForm');
        form.action = "{{ route('client.info.get') }}" + "/" + inputValue;
        form.submit();
});
```

output route = https://example.com/info/google.com

```
public function getInfo(Request $request, $input)
    {
        return $input;
    }
```

it should return input